# Label return zero value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code in ASP.NET but when run the code it returns me 0 value in label lblassest.Text. can anyone tell me where is the problem?

C# Code :

```
if (reader.Read())
            {
                decimal price;
                decimal.TryParse(lblcurrentbtc.Text, out price);
                decimal pr_charges = reader["WallBalan"] == 
                DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(reader["WallBalan"]);
                lblamount.Text = pr_charges.ToString();
                lblassest.Text = ((Convert.ToDecimal(reader["WallBalan"]) * price)).ToString();
                reader.Close();
            }
```

ASP (Frontend) :

```
<asp:Label class="text-dark float-right font-weight-medium" id="lblcurrentbtc" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label class="text-dark mb-1 font-weight-medium" runat="server" ID="lblassest"></asp:Label>
```

Javascript :

```
var baseUrl = "https://api.coinranking.com/v2/coins"
var proxyUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
var apiKey = "coinranking"


fetch(`${proxyUrl}${baseUrl}`, {
method: "GET",
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-access-token': `${apiKey}`,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
}
}).then((response) => {
if (response.ok) {
    response.json().then((json) => {
        console.log(json.data.coins)

        let coinsData = json.data.coins

        if (coinsData.lenght > 0) {
            var cryptoCoins = "";
        }

        coinsData.forEach((coin) => {
            cryptoCoins += "<tr>"
            cryptoCoins += `<td> ${coin.uuid} </td>`;
            cryptoCoins += `<td> ${coin.btcPrice} </td>`;
            cryptoCoins += `<td> ${coin.rank} </td>`;
            cryptoCoins += `<td> ${coin.tier} </td>`;
            cryptoCoins += `<td> ${coin.name} </td>`;
            cryptoCoins += `<td> ${coin.price} </td>`;
            cryptoCoins += `<td> ${coin.symbol} </td>`; "<tr>";
        })
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = cryptoCoins


        document.getElementById('lblcurrentbtc').innerHTML = "";
        var myTab = document.getElementById('table1');
        var objCells = myTab.rows.item(1).cells;
        lblcurrentbtc.innerHTML = lblcurrentbtc.innerHTML + ' ' + 
    objCells.item(5).innerHTML;
    })
   }
  }).catch((error) => {
   console.log(error)
  })
```

Please note that the lblcurrentbtc.Text have value like 54897.56062971018 .

Thx for your helps

Comment: [7 ways to look at the values of variables as you step debug](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/7-ways-to-look-at-the-values-of-variables-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/)

Comment: asp.net? label? What is `lblcurrentbtc`, where is it defined?

Comment: Where did you *set* this Label value? You may be better off using an `<input type=hidden>`

Comment: thx for your replay. I have edited the post and write the necessary code you need.

Comment: A Label (-text) is not posted back to the server, so any value you set in javascript is not seen there. You *need* to use an hidden input to post client-side data back to the server.

Comment: I have used the post back in c# code. By the way can you tell me how use an hidden input to post client-side data back to the server?

Comment: You can set it (and use it) just like a regular input element, it is just not shown to the user. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden).  You can add a "runat=server" (provided you add it from server side) or look in the Request by its name

Answer (score 0):

You are using `decimal.TryParse()` correctly. If the value of price is `0` after calling it then either the contents of your `llblcurrentbtc.Text` is `0`, something that isn't a number or null/empty string.

It's also possible that the `TryParse` line is never reached.

Try setting a breakpoint in your if statement to verify the string value (`lblcurrentbtc.Text`) is as you expect. Your `lblcurrentbtc.Text` may be null or empty string at the point this code runs - the code that assigns a value may happen later.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thx for your replay.Last night I have done a test and think the tryparse and price does not save any value.

Comment: @Black - Which happens if `lblcurrentbtc.Text` is `0`, `null`, or `""`. You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: thx for your replay. I have edited the post and write the necessary code you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I write this code:

```
var lblcurrentbtc = new Label();
var lblamount = new Label();
var lblassest = new Label();
var reader = new Dictionary<string, object>();

reader["WallBalan"] = 2m;
lblcurrentbtc.Text = 54897.56062971018m.ToString();
```

Then I run **your code verbatim** after it:

```
decimal price;
decimal.TryParse(lblcurrentbtc.Text, out price);

decimal pr_charges = reader["WallBalan"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(reader["WallBalan"]);
lblamount.Text = pr_charges.ToString();

lblassest.Text = ((Convert.ToDecimal(reader["WallBalan"]) * price)).ToString();
```

The value of `lblamount.Text` & `lblassest.Text` are `2` & `109795.12125942036`, respectively.

Your code is working fine as it is. Your issue is that `lblcurrentbtc.Text` doesn't contain the value that you think it does.

Comment: Thx for your replay but the lblcurrentbtc.text have contain this value because I have print it and see the value but I don't know why the label return 0 . Last night I have done a test and think the tryparse and price does not save any value.

Comment: @Black - Unless the code you posted in your question is not your actual code, then `lblcurrentbtc.Text` doesn't contain the value you think it does. That's 100% clear. Please post a [mcve] so we can verify everything.

Comment: thx for your replay. I have edited the post and write the necessary code you need.